# dcotrine postgres specidu schema

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

As far as I know, doctrine always uses a `public` schema for Postgres, but is there a way to change the schema name in configs? I can set schema on the entities level `@ORM\Table(schema="internal")` to specify the schema in the query builder, but what about fixtures?

Comment: Fixtures are just objects of your existing entities (i.e. tables), so they're using the schema as well - aren't they?

Comment: well, by default when you run fixtures command, bundle under the hood trying to purge all the data, but in my case it can’t because all d the data is not in the schema with name ‘public’. And its very weird that seems like in doctrine you can’t easily specify which schema to use by default. BTW its not good practice to use ‘public’ schema in postgres

Comment: it's not a duplicate.... I created specific user for that schema, but fixture still trying to purge data in `public` schema

Comment: when I run migration all is good, tables are created in the schema I want, but when I run `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load` it trying to purge data but in reality do nothing all the data still I the tables, because it's still trying to use `public`